# Emberjs - Return value from controller to router

Tags: ember.js

I have a very quick question about the way to communicate between router and controller in Ember.

I know that we can trigger a controller function from the router like this :

`this.controllerFor('application').send('yourFunction');`

But if my function return a value, is it possible to get it in the router ?

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    myFunction: function() {
        return 42;
    }
});
```

Let's say I have this router :

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this.controllerFor('application').send('myfunction');
        // How I can get the '42' here ?
    }
});
```

[edit] My case here is to reload the model like this :

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        var promise = myNewModel();
        this._super(controller, promise);
    }
})
```

But instead of have `myNewModel()` function in the router, I want to have it inside the controller.

I don't set a model function to avoid the user being stuck on a blank page, and after that I load the model.
Actually I reload it twice because I need to have the texte displayed first followed by the images (download from a link in a JSON file) asynchronously.

So I would like to do something like this :

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        var promise = ; //get the value from controller

        this._super(controller, promise);
    }
})
```

Comment: What is ur use case? You can set the value you intend to return to a property of the application controller and just access that after the sending the action.

Comment: I have updated the question for you with the use case.

Comment: Seeing ur last code snippet, u are trying to call a controller function in the setupController. Is this what u need http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yosaro/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you call a controller function in the `setupController` hook of the route

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  },
  setupController:function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    var val = controller.testFunc();
    console.info('Controller Value: ' + val);
  }
});

App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  testFunc: function() {
     return 'yeppppppp';
  }
});
```

[Here is the working demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yosaro/1/edit).

Answer (score 0):

You Could set this 42 as a value of an object

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
somevalue : {},

    myFunction: function() {
        this.set('somevalue' , 42);
    }
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this.controllerFor('application').get(somevalue).doStuff();

    }
});
```

Comment: I could, but I have put 42 as an example, and my value is set dynamically, that's why I need it.